# React-native app inside lerna package

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, lerna

I'm trying to create a new react native application inside a lerna package structure, but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ react-native init app
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Volumes/DADOS/dev/workspace/amplifactory/packages/app
Using yarn v1.6.0
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.6.0
(node:3689) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "workspace-aggregator-8ea62db7-5bb7-4a68-a0d4-fdec926563d9 > @monorepo/admin > babel-loader@7.1.4" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@6".
warning "workspace-aggregator-8ea62db7-5bb7-4a68-a0d4-fdec926563d9 > @monorepo/admin > babel-preset-react-app@3.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "babel-runtime@^6.23.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-8ea62db7-5bb7-4a68-a0d4-fdec926563d9 > @monorepo/admin > eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "babel-eslint@^7.2.3".
warning "workspace-aggregator-8ea62db7-5bb7-4a68-a0d4-fdec926563d9 > @monorepo/ux > react-datetime@2.14.0" has unmet peer dependency "moment@>=2.16.0".
warning "react-native > eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning " > react-native@0.55.4" has unmet peer dependency "react@16.3.1".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved 7 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
info All dependencies
├─ @monorepo/admin@3.0.0
├─ @monorepo/auth@3.0.0
├─ @monorepo/boffice@3.0.0
├─ @monorepo/graphqlserver@3.0.0
├─ @monorepo/studio@3.0.0
├─ app@0.0.1
└─ react-native@0.55.4
✨  Done in 8.38s.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/dev/workspace/amplifactory/packages/app/node_modules/react-native/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at checkNodeVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:306:21)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:300:3)
    at createProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
```

Environment:

- MacOS High Sierra
- node 10.3
- lerna 2.11.0
- yarn 1.6.0

As I can't create it inside my lerna package, I've created the app package outside lerna, then moved to lerna packages folder and changed the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "@monorepo/app",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start-dev": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

After chaning the file I reinstalled it using lerna:

```
$ yarn install
```

When trying to run the app I'm getting the following error:

[image]

My lerna configuration file:

```
{
  "lerna": "2.9.0",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "3.0.0"
}
```

How can I properly add a react-native package to lerna and make it run appropriately?

Comment: The problem is that some modules look for the dependency packages, directly inside there respective node modules folder. Although, lenra maintains a single node_modules folder, with all the node_modules, of the packages. To solve this, you either have to manually symlink the module outside package to node module inside package, or somehow get the package folder inside the node modules of the package.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to run `lerna bootstrap`?  This will install each submodule dependencies and symlink all lerna packages that are dependencies of each other https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/bootstrap

Comment: @shivanshNalwaya any idea how to achieve that?